# replace a button with another under android 4.0

Tags: android, events, button

I have a "`start`" button on my content view, i want to replace it with a "`stop`" button when clicking on it.

i have already defined a "`start`" and a "`stop`" button in `xml` , what should i do next? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a reference to your button in the code:

```
Button stop = (Button) findViewById( R.id.stopButton );
Button start = (Button) findViewById( R.id.startButton );
```

Add `onClickListeners` for both and when start is clicked you add these lines:

```
start.setVisibility( View.GONE );
stop.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

In stops `onClickListener` you do the opposite:

```
start.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
stop.setVisibility( View.GONE );
```

Or you could just let one `Button` handle both start and stop and just change the text of it.

Answer (score 2):

use ToggleButton for this requirement.. 
[Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#ToggleButton)